# SPAQRL create exclusion query

Tags: sparql, ontology, dbpedia, protege, sparqlwrapper

I have this kind of structure

```
<ontology:Louvre>  
<rdf:type ontology:Museum/>
<ontology:preserves rdf:Gioconda/>
<ontology:locatedIn rdf:Paris/>
<ontology:name>Louvre</ontology:name>

<ontology:Gioconda>
<rdf:type ontology:Artwork/>
<ontology:preserved rdf:Louvre/>
<ontology:author rdf:Leonardo/>
<nomeOpera>Gioconda</nomeOpera>

<rdf:Leonardo_Da_Vinci>
<rdf:type ontology:Painter"/>
<ontology:paint ontology:Gioconda"/>
<ontology:paint ontology:Ultima_cena"/>
<name>Leonardo Da Vinci</name>

...(other museum, artist and artwork)
I use "ontology" to indicate my prefix
```

Is it possible to recover the exclusive artists of a museum?

Comment: might be possible, yes.

Comment: :| how? Can you write the query?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and where you get stuck. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
This is the query that i'm looking for

```
SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {
   ?museum ontology:preserves ?artwork .
   ?museum ontology:name "Louvre" .
   ?artwork ontology:author ?author.
    FILTER NOT EXISTS{
        ?museum2 ontology:preserves ?artwork2 .
        ?artwork2 ontology:author ?author .
        FILTER (?museum2 != ?museum)
    }
}
```